# Better notifications (ignore bots)

Tags: phabricator

Most of my Phabricator notifications are now bot (e.g. Jenkins) comments. Is there a built in way to do this, or via a Herald rule? I know how to create a notification through Herald rules, but not sure if I can block notifications, or ignore "Jenkins".